# How do I create a function to return an assigned value from a data frame

Tags: r

I am creating a model to assign fitness to alleles. I have firstly created genomes for a population (which works)

```
locus.info <- list(betalocus=c(A=0.8204,S=0.0512, C=0.1284))
create.genome <- function(locus.info)
{
num.loci <- length(locus.info)
gg <- vector(length=2*num.loci)
for (ll in 1:num.loci) {
alleles <- sample(names(locus.info[[ll]]), size=2, replace=TRUE, 
prob=locus.info[[ll]])
gg[c(ll, ll+num.loci)] <- alleles
}
return(gg)
} 
num.inds <- 30
pop <- data.frame(t(replicate(num.inds, create.genome (locus.info))), 
stringsAsFactors =FALSE)

pop
    X1 X2
1   A  A
2   A  A
3   A  A
4   A  A
5   A  A
6   C  A
7   A  A
8   A  A
9   A  A
10  A  A
11  A  A
12  A  A
13  A  S
14  A  C
15  A  A
16  A  A
17  A  A
18  A  A
19  A  C
20  A  A
21  A  C
22  C  A
23  A  A
24  A  A
25  C  C
26  A  A
27  A  A
28  A  S
29  A  A
30  A  A
```

I then want to create a function to assign a specific fitness to each genotype produced in the population data frame called pop - I have tried this

```
ind_fit<-function(a,b)
{
 pop<-matrix(0,nrow=1,ncol=2)
 pop[1,1]<-a
 pop[1,2]<-b
 indfitness <- ifelse(pop[,1]=="A" & pop[,2]=="A", 0.861,
                ifelse(pop[,1]=="C" & pop[,2]=="C", 1,
                  ifelse(pop[,1]=="S" & pop[,2]=="S", 0.109,
                   ifelse(pop[,1]=="C" & pop[,2]=="A", 0.935,
                     ifelse(pop[,1]=="A" & pop[,2]=="C", 0.935,
                       ifelse(pop[,1]=="A" & pop[,2]=="S", 0.979,                                                     
                         ifelse(pop[,1]=="S" & pop[,2]=="A", 0.979, 0.498)
                 ))))))
 return(indfitness)
 }
```

however every value i enter i always get 0.498 returned despite of what the genotypes (letters) are in the pop data frame

```
 ind_fit(1,1) 
 0.498
```

How do i get it so if for example in my pop data frame i have 'AA' i get 0.861 returned ?

i expect to get the first row which is 'AA' a return of 0.861 not 0.498

Comment: Please add a small test data set, the results you get, and the results you expect.    I don't think you need the first function in the question if you are positive the results are giving what you expect.

Comment: Also in your code `pop` is a matrix not a data frame.

Comment: Your function works find for me if I do `a<-"A"; b<-"A"; ind_fit(a,b)`  though as mentioned below it's not the nicest way to write the function.

Comment: Looking at your edit, `ind_fit(1,1)`  is going to give you .498 since 1 is not "A", "C" or "S".   I think the error is that you mean `ind_fit(pop$X1, pop$X2)`  Also there are other problems with the function ... why are you making that pop matrix at all?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am very new to R, i realise i was inputting the wrong thing now, thank you for clarifying that.

Comment: And i am not entirely sure why it is being made into a matrix as part of the function code I received from somebody else, so I have just been working with it like that

Comment: The `pop` inside the function is not the same as the `pop` that you created with your other function.  Inside the function is like a separate universe that only exists as long as you are inside the function and doesn't refer to anything outside the function unless it was passed in.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing this in a situation where you will always have a two column dataframe with the letters then (assuming you don't want to totally rethink such as using the tidyverse).

```
ind_fit<-function(pop)
{

    indfitness <- ifelse(pop[,1]=="A" & pop[,2]=="A", 0.861,
            ifelse(pop[,1]=="C" & pop[,2]=="C", 1,
              ifelse(pop[,1]=="S" & pop[,2]=="S", 0.109,
               ifelse(pop[,1]=="C" & pop[,2]=="A", 0.935,
                 ifelse(pop[,1]=="A" & pop[,2]=="C", 0.935,
                   ifelse(pop[,1]=="A" & pop[,2]=="S", 0.979,                                                     
                     ifelse(pop[,1]=="S" & pop[,2]=="A", 0.979, 0.498)
             ))))))
      return(indfitness)
 }
```

Personally I would rather use a hash than either this or the dplyr solution but that's the beauty of r. Or just do it in base R.

```
pop <- data.frame(X1 = c("A", "A"), X2 = c("C", "S"))
ind_fit<-function(pop)
{

  pop$indfitness[pop$X1=="A" & pop$X2=="A"]<-0.861
  pop$indfitness[pop$X1=="C" & pop$X2=="C"] <- 1
  pop$indfitness[pop$X1=="S" & pop$X2=="S"] <-0.109
  pop$indfitness[pop$X1=="C" & pop$X2=="A"] <- 0.935
  pop$indfitness[pop$X1=="A" & pop$X2=="C"] <- 0.935
  pop$indfitness[pop$X1=="A" & pop$X2=="S"] <- 0.979                                                     
  pop$indfitness[pop$X1=="S" & pop$X2=="A"] <- 0.979

  pop  # or pop$indfitness depending on what you want.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `case_when` statement in `dplyr`. If I use the `pop` dataframe which has columns `X1` and `X2` the following code should do what you want.

```
library(dplyr)
popf = function(pop) {
    pop %>% mutate(
        result = case_when(
            X1=="A" & X2=="A" ~ 0.861,
            X1=="C" & X2=="C" ~ 1,
            X1=="S" & X2=="S" ~ 0.109,
            X1=="C" & X2=="A" ~ 0.935,
            X1=="A" & X2=="C" ~ 0.935,
            X1=="A" & X2=="S" ~ 0.979,
            X1=="S" & X2=="A" ~ 0.979,
            TRUE ~ 0.498)
        )
}
popf(pop)
```

Edited to add a function wrapper.

Comment: You'd want to wrap that into a function that takes pop as the argument.